# How can I store per user data in Spring session?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I wanted to store for each user which logs in , his id in Spring session. What I did was:

```
HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder
.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);

    session.getServletContext().setAttribute("userId", userId);
```

When I needed the id, i was doing

```
 HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder
                .getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();  
 HttpSession session = request.getSession();
 Long userId = (Long) session.getServletContext().getAttribute("userId");
```

First user logs in , get session id is ok.

Second user logs in , the session id is overrwritten ( i see because each next action of first user, gets the user id of second user)

What is the proper way to achieve this, obviously im not understanding the session properly?

Appreciate all the advices

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're storing the attribute in the `ServletContext`, which is shared amongst all sessions of the *same webapp.*

You should be storing the attribute in the `HttpSession` itself:

`session.setAttribute("userId", userId);`

Then retrieving it:

`Long userId = (Long) session.getAttribute("userId");`

Comment: damn, now i see what ive done, thanx. however, im not managing to get the id back. after the id has been set, the server hangs without the exceptions and it never actually reaches the part of retrieving the id. any hints on that ?

Comment: It sounds like you should debug your server-side code to determine where the application is hanging.

Answer (score 1):

You're not using the `HttpSession` here, you're using the `ServletContext`, as the name implies, which is a singleton.

```
session.setAttribute("userId", userId);

Long userId = (Long) session.getAttribute("userId");
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer saving sessionBean object in HttpSession ...
you can create bean with data which you want to keep in session

session.setAttribute("sessionData",sessionBean);